# How to implement a Progress Bar with multiple instances of application?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I added a key to the Registry such that when I right click on a JPG file I see a new "Transform" option that actually runs my application. 
I would like to implement a Progress Bar to see the progress of the Transformations of all JPGs.
The problem is when I select N JPGs and apply "Transform" on them, my application runs N times (each time with one selected JPG). This way, in my application I can be aware of a single Transformation progress only.
Could you suggest a workaround to implement the Progress Bar ? (maybe to create some temporary file, or something like that...?)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well my suggestion to you would be not to run your application more than once, but making your application open several windows, that will just communicate with eachother. Why try to communcate through files, which are bound to have problems, when you can just create a new window within your current application and avoid that.

Alterntively, you may look into cross process communication, which is very possible. i think what you should be looking for in this case, is "remoting". Make sure to select the accepted answer!